# How to create multiple reducers with multiple modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I still don't have much experience with Redux.

But I have a situation at work where we will have an application with several modules.

Each module will have its own `store`.

I'm not able to merge all these stores into one store and then create a general store for all the project.

Could you tell me how can i do this?

[image]

[image]

```js
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";

const rootReducer1 = combineReducers({
  reducerA: reducerA,
  reducerB: reducerB,
  reducerC: reducerC
});

export const store1 = createStore(rootReducer1);

/*****/

import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";

const rootReducer2 = combineReducers({
  reducerD: reducerD,
  reducerE: reducerE,
  reducerF: reducerF
});

export const store2 = createStore(rootReducer2);

/*****/

import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";

import store1 from "../modules/module1/reducers";
import store2 from "../modules/module2/reducers";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  store1: store1,
  store2: store2
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer);

/*****/

import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

import { store } from "./store";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <App />
    </ReduxProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

I created a test project in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dust-3duip?file=/src/index.js) just to demonstrate the idea of what the project will be like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[combineReducers(reducers)](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) helper function turns an object whose values are different reducing functions into a single reducing function. It can't combine multiple stores.

Besides, the best practice is [Only One Redux Store Per App](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#only-one-redux-store-per-app)

> A standard Redux application should only have a single Redux store instance, which will be used by the whole application

You can have each module act as a first-level slice on the redux state tree like this:

`store.js`:

```
// module 1
const rootReducer1 = combineReducers({
  reducerA: reducerA,
  reducerB: reducerB,
  reducerC: reducerC
});

// module 2
const rootReducer2 = combineReducers({
  reducerD: reducerD,
  reducerE: reducerE,
  reducerF: reducerF
});

// App
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  module1: rootReducer1,
  module2: rootReducer2
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

The structure of the redux state tree will be like this:

```
{
  module1: {
    reducerA: {},
    reducerB: {},
    reducerC: {}
  },
  module2: {
    reducerD: {},
    reducerE: {},
    reducerF: {}
  },
}
```

If the module becomes large in the future, you can split it into a separate application with its own redux store.